# ASP.NET MVC System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

working on my project, and cant figure out one more thing. On this part I cannot have a null `IPagedList<Product_list> products = null;`, but when I create `IPagedList<Product_list> products = new IPagedList<Product_list>` it says that I cannot do that either.

Comment: What "says you cannot do that"?  Please show the code that produces the error.  Your first line here is valid, the second isn't because you can't call a constructor on an interface.  The error sounds like it's coming from an extension method that you're calling.

Comment: Your second line is a syntax error, `IPagedList` is probably an interface which can't be initialized directly.

Comment: You need to have a concrete implementation of IPagedList.  Something like:  IPagedList<Product_list> products = new PagedList<Product_list>();

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize a Interface. You need to initialize a class that implements an interface.

So if you had:

```
public interface IPuppy
{
   void Bark();
}
```

You need:

```
public class Puppy : IPuppy
{
   public void Bark()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Bark!");
   }
}
```

More info on interfaces at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you appear to be calling an extension method on a `null` collection.  As you say, you initialize a collection like this:

```
IPagedList<Product_list> products = null;
```

So `products` is now `null`.  Based on the error, it sounds like you do something like this next:

```
products = products.Where(p => someCondition);
```

This would fail because, as the error states, `products` is `null`.  The syntax allows you to call an extension method on a `null` object, mostly because extension methods are just syntactic sugar.  But it's just going to return an error at runtime.  You need to initialize `products` to a valid instance first.